# How to pass —help to extension command?

Tags: git

I have an extension command git-foo.  If I invoke this as git foo —help, it tries to open an html page, which just errors.  -h works, so presumably git is parsing this magical option before determining that it’s an extension command and not a builtin.

This is fairly inconvenient for true extension commands, and I’m wondering if there’s any way to make git forward this to the command’s implementation.

Comment: If I remember right, this has been reported on the Git mailing list as a Git bug, but nobody knows what to do about it. You might search the [Git mailing list archives](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitCommunity) and see what you can find.

Comment: `--help` is an option of `git` instead of any of its sub commands like `init`, `add`, `checkout`, etc. `git foo --help` is identical to `git --help foo`, and is internally converted into `git help foo`. It works before the sub command starts while `-h` is handled by the sub command.